# Sorting logs using regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out how to sort logs for example...

1. User: test
2. Level: user
3. Domain: localhost
4. Time:  12pm
5. Blah: INFO
6. Date: 07-12-2016
7. Ip:  127.0.0.1

I would like the output text to be this also there is tab spaces.

User:Level:Domain:Time:Blah:Date:IP

Comment: What do you want to sort? Are you asking how to sort on an arbitrary field? In what language? What does this question have to do with regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question right, you're talking not about sorting, but about parsing. You have log strings which you want to convert to another format. The regex to match your log string would be

```
(?P<User>[^:]+):(?P<Level>[^:]+):(?P<Domain>[^:]+):(?P<Time>[^:]+):(?P<Blah>[^:]+):(?P<Date>[^:]+):(?P<IP>[^:]+)
```

However, since you have so many groups, it could be done much more efficiently, here's an example in python

```
import re
logString = "User:Level:Domain:Time:Blah:Date:IP"
logGroups = ["User", "Level", "Domain", "Time", "Blah", "Date", "IP"]
reLogGroups = "(?P<"+">[^:]+):(?P<".join(logGroups)+">[^:]+)"
matchLogGroups = re.search(reLogGroups,logString)
if matchLogGroups:
    counter = 1
    for logGroup in logGroups:
        print(str(counter)+". " + logGroup + ": " + matchLogGroups.group(logGroup) + "\n")
        counter += 1
```

The output is

```
1. User: User

2. Level: Level

3. Domain: Domain

4. Time: Time

5. Blah: Blah

6. Date: Date

7. IP: IP
```